# Sitecore - Deleting Items from the workbox

Tags: c#, workflow, sitecore

Is it possible to delete entries out of the workbox? I have some old items that still are in a draft state. When i press view item / view page I get the content tree without that specific item / a not found error. The workbox however is still showing those old and deleted files.

Comment: What's exact Sitecore version?

Comment: Also, have you een rebuilding your indexes?

Comment: Just another guess: have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. Sitecore.NET 6.1.0 (rev. 090630). I have tried to rebuild the indexes and i cleared the browser cache.

Comment: Have you ever customized your Workbox application? If you go to the /sitecore/shell/Applications/Workbox/Workbox.xml, what class is there in CodeBeside?

Comment: <CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm,Sitecore.Client"/>

Comment: that's quite strange. If you select the "Draft" state item itself under the workflow definition item /system/worflows/your workflow/draft, and toggle Navigate -> Links button. Any items are showing up as references?

Comment: Solution to this one: Clean up database. As I figured i had already tried everything, i just did a clean up database and this worked out fine :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for the replies to my question.
I have tried all of the things suggested and found nothing to be working.

What I've done:

- Rebuild link database
- Cleared browser cache
- Checked the items still in the workflow for excistense (They didn't even excist in the content tree anymore...)
- Clean up database <- this one helped me out

Comment: Sitecore can do funny things with the database sometimes.... Rebuilding the link database often helps with things when the database is behaving "funny".